# Joomla get plain article tags in blog view

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

is it possible to get the article tags in joomlas blogview in plain text for every single article? i found a snippet, but it renders the articles tags in html...

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_tags', 1) && !empty($this->item->tags)) : ?>
    <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The tags are shown using a JLayout. The one in question is in `/layouts/joomla/content/tags.php`.
JLayouts are easily overridable in your template.
Just copy that file (or create a new one) to `templates/your_template/html/layouts/joomla/content/tags.php` and adjust it as needed. Joomla will then automatically use that layout instead to show the tags.

Answer (score 1):

thanks bakual, I found a another solution for my problem:

in the template `blog.php` I added the following code to display the specific article tags in plain text format:

```
foreach ($item->tags->itemTags as $tag) echo $tag->title." "
```

Answer (score 0):

I correct that one into:

```
<?php foreach ($item->tags->itemTags as $tag) : echo $tag->title; endforeach; ?>
```

Anyway it works!
Thank you user3014931